# beautifulsoup-returns-none-even-though-the-td -class=titlecolumn-element exist

Tags: web-scraping

`enter code here` I am writing code to scrape the https://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250

I tried using beautiful soup,requests and re to scrape data from the imdb.com of the top rated movies title.

```
#Import the library to query a website
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
#specify the url
    imdb_link="https://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250"
    link=requests.get(imdb_link).text

    soup=BeautifulSoup(re.sub("<!--|-->","", link),'lxml')
    print(soup.prettify())

    table=soup.find('table',class_='chart full-width')
    print(table)

    tds=table.find_all(class_='titlecolumn')
    print(tds)
```

error getting [] after output of print(tds) expecting the title of the top rated movies  as text.

Comment: typo in the last line: ```tds = table.find_all('td', class_='titleColumn')```

Comment: Also, there's no need to remove comments. remove the re.sub: ```soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')```

Comment: @Xosrov I removed the comments, but I am not getting the error which you point out in tds = table.find_all('td', class_='titleColumn') , I am doing this by following the course , but there it is giving the correct result.could you help me to understand it better

Comment: There is no error, the find_all doesn't find the match because you wrote it incorrectly. The class is ```td``` which you didn't write, and the ```titleColumn``` is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

A more minimalist approach using `re` only, which also extracts title info and rating:

```py
import requests
import re
page = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250")
allRes = re.findall(r'" alt="(.+?)".*?title="(.*?)".*?strong.*?"(.*?)"', page.text, re.DOTALL)
for (name, moreInfo, rating) in allRes:
    print(name + ", " + moreInfo + ", " + rating)
```

The tuples in the for loop are the extracted info. I'm not sure if this works on other parts of the website though (you can test and see).

Edit: Here's the regex at [work](https://regex101.com/r/WVNiL8/1), and here's a less intelligible [chart](https://jex.im/regulex/#!cmd=export&flags=&re=%22%20alt%3D%22(.%2B%3F)%22.*%3Ftitle%3D%22(.*%3F)%22.*%3Fstrong.*%3F%22(.*%3F)%22).

Comment: Yes its working fine and giving the required title, but could you please point out the issue in my problem,and explain your code @Xosrov

Comment: @ShivangiSingh sure, I'll add a comment on your post and an edit on mine

Answer (score 0):

You can use select() to get the data quite easily.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

imdb_link = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250"
link = requests.get(imdb_link).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')

divs = soup.select(".titleColumn")
titles = [div.find('a').text for div in divs]
indexes = [div.find('a').previousSibling.strip() for div in divs]
dates = [div.find('span').text for div in divs]


print(list( zip (indexes, titles, dates)))
```

Outputs:

```
[('1.', 'The Shawshank Redemption', '(1994)'), ('2.', 'The Godfather', '(1972)'), ('3.', 'The Godfather: Part II', '(1974)'), ('4.', 'The Dark Knight', '(2008)'), ('5.', '12 Angry Men', '(1957)'), ('6.', "Schindler's List", '(1993)'), ('7.', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', '(2003)'), ('8.', 'Pulp Fiction', '(1994)'), ('9.', 'The Good, the Bad and the Ugly', '(1966)'), ('10.', 'Fight Club', '(1999)'), ('11.', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring', '(2001)'), ('12.', 'Forrest Gump', '(1994)'), ('13.', 'Inception', '(2010)'), ('14.', 'Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back', '(1980)'), ('15.', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers', '(2002)'), ('16.', "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", '(1975)'), ('17.', 'Goodfellas', '(1990)'), ('18.', 'The Matrix', '(1999)'), ('19.', 'Avengers: Endgame', '(2019)'), ('20.', 'Seven Samurai', '(1954)'), ('21.', 'Se7en', '(1995)'), ('22.', 'City of God', '(2002)'), ('23.', 'Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope', '(1977)'), ('24.', 'The Silence of the Lambs', '(1991)'), ('25.', "It's a Wonderful Life", '(1946)'), ('26.', 'La vita è bella', '(1997)'), ('27.', 'Spirited Away', '(2001)'), ('28.', 'Saving Private Ryan', '(1998)'), ('29.', 'The Usual Suspects', '(1995)'), ('30.', 'Leon', '(1994)'), ('31.', 'The Green Mile', '(1999)'), ('32.', 'Interstellar', '(2014)'), ('33.', 'Psycho', '(1960)'), ('34.', 'American History X', '(1998)'), ('35.', 'City Lights', '(1931)'), ('36.', 'Casablanca', '(1942)'), ('37.', 'Once Upon a Time in the West', '(1968)'), ('38.', 'The Pianist', '(2002)'), ('39.', 'Modern Times', '(1936)'), ('40.', 'Untouchable', '(2011)'), ('41.', 'The Departed', '(2006)'), ('42.', 'Back to the Future', '(1985)'), ('43.', 'Terminator 2: Judgment Day', '(1991)'), ('44.', 'Whiplash', '(2014)'), ('45.', 'The Lion King', '(1994)'), ('46.', 'Rear Window', '(1954)'), ('47.', 'Gladiator', '(2000)'), ('48.', 'Raiders of the Lost Ark', '(1981)'), ('49.', 'The Prestige', '(2006)'), ('50.', 'Apocalypse Now', '(1979)'), ('51.', 'Memento', '(2000)'), ('52.', 'Alien', '(1979)'), ('53.', 'Grave of the Fireflies', '(1988)'), ('54.', 'Cinema Paradiso', '(1988)'), ('55.', 'The Great Dictator', '(1940)'), ('56.', 'Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse', '(2018)'), ('57.', 'Sunset Blvd.', '(1950)'), ('58.', 'The Lives of Others', '(2006)'), ('59.', 'Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb', '(1964)'), ('60.', 'Avengers: Infinity War', '(2018)'), ('61.', 'Paths of Glory', '(1957)'), ('62.', 'Django Unchained', '(2012)'), ('63.', 'The Shining', '(1980)'), ('64.', 'WALL·E', '(2008)'), ('65.', 'Princess Mononoke', '(1997)'), ('66.', 'Witness for the Prosecution', '(1957)'), ('67.', 'Oldeuboi', '(2003)'), ('68.', 'The Dark Knight Rises', '(2012)'), ('69.', 'Aliens', '(1986)'), ('70.', 'American Beauty', '(1999)'), ('71.', 'Once Upon a Time in America', '(1984)'), ('72.', 'Coco', '(2017)'), ('73.', 'Das Boot', '(1981)'), ('74.', 'Citizen Kane', '(1941)'), ('75.', 'Braveheart', '(1995)'), ('76.', 'Vertigo', '(1958)'), ('77.', 'North by Northwest', '(1959)'), ('78.', 'Kimi no na wa.', '(2016)'), ('79.', 'Reservoir Dogs', '(1992)'), ('80.', 'Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi', '(1983)'), ('81.', 'M - Eine Stadt sucht einen Mörder', '(1931)'), ('82.', 'Amadeus', '(1984)'), ('83.', 'Requiem for a Dream', '(2000)'), ('84.', 'Dangal', '(2016)'), ('85.', '3 Idiots', '(2009)'), ('86.', 'Toy Story', '(1995)'), ('87.', '2001: A Space Odyssey', '(1968)'), ('88.', 'Taare Zameen Par', '(2007)'), ('89.', 'Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind', '(2004)'), ('90.', 'Lawrence of Arabia', '(1962)'), ('91.', 'A Clockwork Orange', '(1971)'), ('92.', "Singin' in the Rain", '(1952)'), ('93.', 'Amélie', '(2001)'), ('94.', 'Inglourious Basterds', '(2009)'), ('95.', 'Double Indemnity', '(1944)'), ('96.', 'Taxi Driver', '(1976)'), ('97.', 'Full Metal Jacket', '(1987)'), ('98.', 'Bicycle Thieves', '(1948)'), ('99.', 'To Kill a Mockingbird', '(1962)'), ('100.', 'Good Will Hunting', '(1997)'), ('101.', 'The Kid', '(1921)'), ('102.', 'The Sting', '(1973)'), ('103.', 'The Hunt', '(2012)'), ('104.', 'Toy Story 3', '(2010)'), ('105.', 'Snatch', '(2000)'), ('106.', 'Scarface', '(1983)'), ('107.', 'The Apartment', '(1960)'), ('108.', 'For a Few Dollars More', '(1965)'), ('109.', 'Metropolis', '(1927)'), ('110.', 'Monty Python and the Holy Grail', '(1975)'), ('111.', 'L.A. Confidential', '(1997)'), ('112.', 'Jodaeiye Nader az Simin', '(2011)'), ('113.', 'Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade', '(1989)'), ('114.', 'Up', '(2009)'), ('115.', 'Rashomon', '(1950)'), ('116.', 'All About Eve', '(1950)'), ('117.', 'Batman Begins', '(2005)'), ('118.', 'Some Like It Hot', '(1959)'), ('119.', 'Yojimbo', '(1961)'), ('120.', 'Downfall', '(2004)'), ('121.', 'Unforgiven', '(1992)'), ('122.', 'Die Hard', '(1988)'), ('123.', 'Heat', '(1995)'), ('124.', 'The Treasure of the Sierra Madre', '(1948)'), ('125.', 'Incendies', '(2010)'), ('126.', 'Ikiru', '(1952)'), ('127.', 'Green Book', '(2018)'), ('128.', 'Raging Bull', '(1980)'), ('129.', 'Bacheha-Ye aseman', '(1997)'), ('130.', 'The Great Escape', '(1963)'), ('131.', "Pan's Labyrinth", '(2006)'), ('132.', 'Chinatown', '(1974)'), ('133.', 'My Neighbour Totoro', '(1988)'), ('134.', "Howl's Moving Castle", '(2004)'), ('135.', 'The Third Man', '(1949)'), ('136.', 'Ran', '(1985)'), ('137.', 'Babam ve Oglum', '(2005)'), ('138.', 'Judgment at Nuremberg', '(1961)'), ('139.', 'El secreto de sus ojos', '(2009)'), ('140.', 'The Gold Rush', '(1925)'), ('141.', 'A Beautiful Mind', '(2001)'), ('142.', 'The Bridge on the River Kwai', '(1957)'), ('143.', 'Casino', '(1995)'), ('144.', 'Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels', '(1998)'), ('145.', 'The Seventh Seal', '(1957)'), ('146.', 'Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri', '(2017)'), ('147.', 'On the Waterfront', '(1954)'), ('148.', 'The Wolf of Wall Street', '(2013)'), ('149.', 'The Elephant Man', '(1980)'), ('150.', 'Inside Out', '(2015)'), ('151.', 'V for Vendetta', '(2005)'), ('152.', 'Mr. Smith Goes to Washington', '(1939)'), ('153.', 'Room', '(2015)'), ('154.', 'Warrior', '(2011)'), ('155.', 'Blade Runner', '(1982)'), ('156.', 'Dial M for Murder', '(1954)'), ('157.', 'There Will Be Blood', '(2007)'), ('158.', 'No Country for Old Men', '(2007)'), ('159.', 'The Sixth Sense', '(1999)'), ('160.', 'Wild Strawberries', '(1957)'), ('161.', 'The General', '(1926)'), ('162.', 'Trainspotting', '(1996)'), ('163.', 'Andhadhun', '(2018)'), ('164.', 'Gone with the Wind', '(1939)'), ('165.', 'The Thing', '(1982)'), ('166.', 'Fargo', '(1996)'), ('167.', 'Come and See', '(1985)'), ('168.', 'Finding Nemo', '(2003)'), ('169.', 'Gran Torino', '(2008)'), ('170.', 'The Deer Hunter', '(1978)'), ('171.', 'Shutter Island', '(2010)'), ('172.', 'The Big Lebowski', '(1998)'), ('173.', 'Kill Bill: Vol. 1', '(2003)'), ('174.', 'Sherlock Jr.', '(1924)'), ('175.', 'Cool Hand Luke', '(1967)'), ('176.', 'Tôkyô monogatari', '(1953)'), ('177.', 'Mary and Max', '(2009)'), ('178.', 'Rebecca', '(1940)'), ('179.', 'Hacksaw Ridge', '(2016)'), ('180.', 'Jurassic Park', '(1993)'), ('181.', 'How to Train Your Dragon', '(2010)'), ('182.', 'Gone Girl', '(2014)'), ('183.', 'Relatos salvajes', '(2014)'), ('184.', 'The Truman Show', '(1998)'), ('185.', 'Stalker', '(1979)'), ('186.', 'Sunrise: A Song of Two Humans', '(1927)'), ('187.', 'The Grand Budapest Hotel', '(2014)'), ('188.', 'In the Name of the Father', '(1993)'), ('189.', 'Stand by Me', '(1986)'), ('190.', 'It Happened One Night', '(1934)'), ('191.', 'Into the Wild', '(2007)'), ('192.', 'Platoon', '(1986)'), ('193.', 'Memories of Murder', '(2003)'), ('194.', 'Network', '(1976)'), ('195.', 'Life of Brian', '(1979)'), ('196.', 'Persona', '(1966)'), ('197.', 'Ben-Hur', '(1959)'), ('198.', '12 Years a Slave', '(2013)'), ('199.', 'Million Dollar Baby', '(2004)'), ('200.', 'Hotel Rwanda', '(2004)'), ('201.', 'Before Sunrise', '(1995)'), ('202.', 'Prisoners', '(2013)'), ('203.', 'Eskiya', '(1996)'), ('204.', 'Mad Max: Fury Road', '(2015)'), ('205.', 'Neon Genesis Evangelion: The End of Evangelion', '(1997)'), ('206.', "Hachi: A Dog's Tale", '(2009)'), ('207.', 'Rush', '(2013)'), ('208.', 'The Wages of Fear', '(1953)'), ('209.', 'Logan', '(2017)'), ('210.', 'The 400 Blows', '(1959)'), ('211.', 'Catch Me If You Can', '(2002)'), ('212.', 'Spotlight', '(2015)'), ('213.', 'Andrei Rublev', '(1966)'), ('214.', 'Amores Perros', '(2000)'), ('215.', 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2', '(2011)'), ('216.', "La passion de Jeanne d'Arc", '(1928)'), ('217.', 'Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind', '(1984)'), ('218.', 'The Princess Bride', '(1987)'), ('219.', 'Rocky', '(1976)'), ('220.', 'Barry Lyndon', '(1975)'), ('221.', 'Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid', '(1969)'), ('222.', 'Rang De Basanti', '(2006)'), ('223.', 'Monsters, Inc.', '(2001)'), ('224.', 'Dead Poets Society', '(1989)'), ('225.', 'The Grapes of Wrath', '(1940)'), ('226.', 'The Maltese Falcon', '(1941)'), ('227.', 'The Terminator', '(1984)'), ('228.', 'Ah-ga-ssi', '(2016)'), ('229.', 'La Haine', '(1995)'), ('230.', 'Gandhi', '(1982)'), ('231.', 'In the Mood for Love', '(2000)'), ('232.', 'Donnie Darko', '(2001)'), ('233.', 'Les Diaboliques', '(1955)'), ('234.', 'Groundhog Day', '(1993)'), ('235.', 'Raise the Red Lantern', '(1991)'), ('236.', 'The Help', '(2011)'), ('237.', 'The Wizard of Oz', '(1939)'), ('238.', 'Guardians of the Galaxy', '(2014)'), ('239.', 'Jaws', '(1975)'), ('240.', 'Before Sunset', '(2004)'), ('241.', 'Laputa: Castle in the Sky', '(1986)'), ('242.', 'Paris, Texas', '(1984)'), ('243.', 'Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl', '(2003)'), ('244.', 'Akira', '(1988)'), ('245.', 'Beauty and the Beast', '(1991)'), ('246.', 'Gangs of Wasseypur', '(2012)'), ('247.', 'Drishyam', '(2015)'), ('248.', 'Three Colours: Red', '(1994)'), ('249.', 'Song of the Sea', '(2014)'), ('250.', 'The Exorcist', '(1973)')]
```

Otherwise to fix you code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
#specify the url
imdb_link = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250"
link = requests.get(imdb_link).text

soup=BeautifulSoup(re.sub("<!--|-->","", link),'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())

table=soup.find('table', {"class":'chart full-width'})
print(table)

tds=table.find_all("td", {"class": 'titleColumn'})
print(tds)
```

If you want to remove comments you can use a lambda to get all instances of a comment and extract them from the soup.

```
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in comments]
```

It might be better than a "greedy" regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna stick to `.find()` and `.find_all()` in order to achieve the same then the following should work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

imdb_link = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250"

link = requests.get(imdb_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(link.text,'lxml')

for items in soup.find("table",class_="chart").find_all(class_="titleColumn"):
    position = items.contents[0].strip().split(".")[0]
    movies = items.find("a",title=True).get_text(strip=True)
    year = items.find("span").get_text(strip=True).strip("(").strip(")")
    rating = items.find_next_sibling().strong.text
    print(position,movies,year,rating)
```

Output are like:

```
1 The Shawshank Redemption 1994 9.2
2 The Godfather 1972 9.2
3 The Godfather: Part II 1974 9.0
4 The Dark Knight 2008 9.0
5 12 Angry Men 1957 8.9
6 Schindler's List 1993 8.9
```